# Windows IOT - Raspberry pi not connecting to wifi

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3, windows-10-iot-core, windowsiot

I have a raspberry pi 3 running windows IOT and it works fine when on a LAN connection. However the issue is that I want it to be on wifi. I have set the wifi connection up and set it to automatically connect and if I then remove the LAN cable everything works fine. But when I reboot the pi it refuses to automatically connect to the wifi. If I go back to the settings and select my wifi network it has the "Connect Automatically" box checked but when I click connect it asks me again for the password...

It is as if it is not saving the password for my network. How do I fix this issue?

Comment: I reproduced your issue. It seems the saved wifi profile lost after restart. I have reported this issue.

Comment: It is amazing the bugs I see that make it all the way through the previews and into the release builds.  Microsoft, please put a feedback hub application on the IoT devices themselves, and/or make IoT a first-class Device Type in the Feedback Hub itself.  Rita, this is not directed at you personally, at all.  You are excellent.

Comment: Thanks for doing that Rita.